# How do iterate over all cells in a named range in Aspose.Cells for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I'm working with .Net Apose.Cells.
I am trying to figure out to iterate over all the cells in a named range.

**I retrieve the named range from the workbook:**

```
Range range = AsposeWorkbook.Worksheets.GetRangeByName(rangeName);
```

I would like to set the value for each cell in the named range to zero (0).
How do I do this?
What is the best method for iterating over cells in a named range?

Thanks,
JB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the cells of your range using the **Range.GetEnumerator()** method. Once you have access to your **Cell** object, then you can set its value to 0 using **Cell.PutValue()** method. Please see the following sample code, its comments and example output

```
//Load your excel file
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("s1.xlsx");

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = workbook.Worksheets[0];

//THis way you can create range on runtime
Range rn = ws.Cells.CreateRange("A1:D6");
rn.Name = "MyRange";

//Access your range as you have been doing before
Range range = workbook.Worksheets.GetRangeByName("MyRange");

//Iterate all the cells in your range, print their names and values
IEnumerator e = range.GetEnumerator();

while (e.MoveNext())
{
    Cell c = (Cell)e.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name + ": " + c.StringValue);

    //Set value to 0
    c.PutValue(0);
}
```

**Example Console Output**

```
A1: 27
B1: 92
C1: 58
D1: 58
A2: 75
B2: 21
C2: 61
D2: 27
A3: 55
B3: 49
C3: 73
D3: 92
A4: 6
B4: 7
C4: 2
D4: 62
A5: 18
B5: 75
C5: 76
D5: 32
A6: 32
B6: 63
C6: 18
D6: 34
```

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Perfect, Thank-you